# Why is margin class not working in bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap-4

I am styling a page for my website and do not want any margin left or right for my paragraph at all. But it seems that the margin class is not working at all

```
<div class="p-5 ml-0" id="top_div" style="background: #303030">
            <h3 id="heading">Lorem Ipsum</h3>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
                cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
                proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
            </p>
        </div>
```

I do not want any left or right margin for the div. I have tried using `D-block`  `ml-0 mr-0` even tried `container-fluid` but none of the classes are working. I have added the bootstrap link and it is working perfectly for other parts of the code.

**EDIT**
I just realized this div is inside `<main role="main" class="container">`
but I can not remove the container class because its messing other elements

Complete HTML

```
{% extends "blog/base.html" %}
{% block content %}
    <script src='https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js'></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <style type="text/css">
        .card{
            color: white;
        }
        #top_div{
            color: white
        }
        #heading{
            color: #F5820D;
        }
        .card2{
            background: #F0F0F0;
        }
        .footer{
            color: white;
        }
        .borders{
            border-width:3px !important;
        }

    </style>
    

        <div class="D-block p-5 ml-0" id="top_div" style="background: #303030">
            <h3 id="heading">Lorem Ipsum</h3>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
                cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
                proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
            </p>
        </div> 

        <div class="row">
            <div class="card col-sm text-center m-3 p-4"style="background: #FFCB2B ">
                <i class="fa fa-handshake-o" style="font-size:28px;"></i>

                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiu
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="card col-sm text-center m-3 p-4" style="background: #FFA611">
                <i class="fa fa-handshake-o" style="font-size:28px;"></i>
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiu 
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="card col-sm text-center m-3 p-4" style="background: #F5820D" >
                <i class="fa fa-handshake-o" style="font-size:28px;"></i>
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiu 
                </p>
            </div>
        
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="card2 col-sm text-center m-3 p-4">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate ve
            </div>
            <div class="card2 col-sm text-center m-3 p-4">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate ve
            </div>
            <div class="card2 col-sm text-center m-3 p-4" >
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate ve
            </div>
        
        </div>  
        <!-- <div class="row text-center mb-3" style="background:#303030 ">
            <div class="footer col-sm m-2 p-2">
                <h4 class="p-1" style="background: #FFA611 ">Lorem</h4>
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris n
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="footer col-sm m-2 p-2">
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris n
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="footer col-sm m-2 p-2">
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris n
                </p>
            </div>
        </div> -->
        <div class="row text-center">
            <div class="col-sm mt-4 p-2" style="font-size: 144px; color: #FFA611">
                <!-- <i class="fa fa-search fa-lg"></i> -->
                <i class="fas fa-blog fa-lg"></i>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm mt-4">
                <div class="row mb-4 border-top border-bottom borders">
                        <h2 class="col-md-1 text-left mt-3">1</h2>
                        <p class="col-md-8 text-left">e et dolore magna aliqua. magna aliqua. Ut enim e et dolore magna aliqua. magna aliqua. Ut enim e et dolore magna aliqua. magna aliqua. Ut enim </p> 
                </div>
                <div class="row mb-4 border-bottom borders">
                        <h2 class="col-md-1 text-left mt-3">2</h2>
                        <p class="col-md-8 text-left">e et dolore magna aliqua. magna aliqua. Ut enim e et dolore magna aliqua. magna aliqua. Ut enim e et dolore magna aliqua. magna aliqua. Ut enim </p> 
                </div>
                <div class="row mb-4 border-bottom borders">
                        <h2 class="col-md-1 text-left mt-3">3</h2>
                        <p class="col-md-8 text-left">e et dolore magna aliqua. magna aliqua. Ut enim e et dolore magna aliqua. magna aliqua. Ut enim e et dolore magna aliqua. magna aliqua. Ut enim </p> 
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
            
        </div>
    

{% endblock content%}
```

This is the base html file from where the above code in imherting

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'blog/main.css' %}">

    <!-- if title(not the variable) is passed then if statement and if no title is passed then else -->
    <!-- getting all the common stuff in about and homepage in base.html -->
    <!-- a block is a section that child templates can override -->
    {% if title %}
        <title>Django Blog - {{title}}</title>
    {% else %}
        <title>Django Blog</title>  
    {% endif %}
</head>
<body>
    <header class="site-header">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
          <a class="navbar-brand mr-4" href="{% url 'blog-home' %}">Django Blog</a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarToggle" aria-controls="navbarToggle" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarToggle">
            <div class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
              <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{% url 'blog-home' %}">Home</a>
              <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{% url 'blog-about' %}">About</a>
              <form method="get" class="form-inline my-2my-lg-0 "  action="{% url 'search' %}">
                  <input class="form-control nav-item nav-link text-secondary" type="search" name="query" id="query" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
                  <button class="btn btn-outline-success nav-item nav-link ml-1">Search</button>
              </form>
            </div>
            <!-- Navbar Right Side -->
            <div class="navbar-nav">
              {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{% url 'post-create' %}">New Post</a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{% url 'profile' %}">Profile</a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{% url 'logout' %}">Logout</a>
                

              {% else %}
              <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{% url 'login' %}">Login</a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{% url 'register' %}">Register</a>
              {% endif %}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </header>
    <main role="main" class="container">
          <div>
          {% if messages %}
            {% for message in messages %}
                <div class="alert alert-{{ message.tags }}">
                    {{ message }}
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
          {% endif %}
          {% block content %}{% endblock %}
          
          </div>
        
    </main>

    

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  

</body>
</html>
```

This is a django project that is why I am using an additional base.html

Comment: You're defining padding on the `div` so the paragraph will be padded inside the `div`.

Comment: Probably the parent class of this particular div class might have margins set. Else set margin of body tag to zero

Comment: this div does not have any parent class

Comment: the only styling I have provided to this div is ```#top_div{
   color: white
  }```

Comment: Use "container-fluid" instead of "container".

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="row">
        your DIVs and text gois here
   </div>
</div>
```

In your CSS file add

```
.container-fluid {
    width: 100%;
    padding-right: 0 !important;
    padding-left: 0 !important;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}
```

Comment: Show me your whole HTML page?

Comment: Updated in the question

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, You want something like this.
If it does not accept "margin. You can use ''margin-left : 0px!important;'' in CSS.

style.css :

```
#top_div{
      margin-left:0px!important;
      margin-right:0px!important; }
```

or you can use in your ""div"".

```
<div class="p-5 ml-0" id="top_div" style="background: #303030 margin-left: 0px!important;margin-right: 0px;!important">
            <h3 id="heading">Lorem Ipsum</h3>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
                cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
                proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
            </p>
        </div>
```